# Redirecting URL in WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect a URL in the form of 
`http://a_domain_name.com/2013/08/link_name/feed` to `http://a_domain_name.com/link_name/feed`. I am a WordPress beginner and finding it hard to do this . Whats the best way to do this ?

I tried using the safe redirection plugin with http://domain_name.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/feed to http://domain_name.com/%postname%/feed but it's not working

Comment: Does this resource help? http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Proper Way**

Log into wordpress admin panel and go to the settings>permalinks page.

From here, select the **second to last** option, ie:

*http://domain.com/blogname/blog/sample-post/*

---

**Alternatively, you can create a redirect file. This involves hacking up wordpress a bit. I wouldn't recommend this if you're not comfortable with wordpress & php. To do this, first:**

Open the setting>permalinks page in the admin panel:

Select the last option in the list (custom) and enter something like this:

`/redirect.php?p=%post_id%&a=%author%&c=%category%`

You'll also need to change the two optional forms below to:

**Category base**

`/redirect.php?c=`

**Tag base**

`/redirect.php?t=`

Now, let's create a redirect php file.  Place this in /yourblogname/blog/

```
<?php 


$total=0;

$string = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/';
$fetch = '';

if (isset($_GET['p'])&&!is_null($_GET['p']))
{
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    if ($total ==0) {
        $string.='?p='.$p;      
    } else {
        $string.='&p='.$p;
    }
    $total++;
}
if (isset($_GET['t'])&&!is_null($_GET['t']))
{
    $t = str_replace('/','',$_GET['t']);
    if ($total ==0) {
        $string.='?tag='.$t;
    } else {
        $string.='&tag='.$t;
    }
    $total++;
}
if (isset($_GET['a'])&&!is_null($_GET['a']))
{
    $a = $_GET['a'];
    if ($total ==0) {
        $string.='?a='.$a;
    } else {
        $string.='&a='.$a;
    }
    $total++;
}
if (isset($_GET['s'])&&!is_null($_GET['s']))
{
    $s = $_GET['s'];
    if ($total ==0) {
        $string.='?s='.$s;
    } else {
        $string.='&s='.$s;
    }
    $total++;
}
if (isset($_GET['c'])&&!is_null($_GET['c']))
{
    $c = str_replace('/','',$_GET['c']);
    if ($total ==0) {
        $string.='?category_name='.$c;
    } else {    
        $string.='&category_name='.$c;
    }
    $total++;
}



echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL='.$string.'">';
?>
<style>
html {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=cont>
<p align=center><div style='font-size:72px;text-align:center;' ><?php echo "redirecting..."; ?></p></div>
</div>
</body>
```

We're not done yet. We need to adjust the page we're redirecting to now... (index.php)

```
if (!isset($_GET['p'])) { 
    if (!isset($_GET['category_name']) && !isset($_GET['tag']) && !isset($_GET['s']) && !isset($_GET['search']) ) {
            include('newhome.php'); //frontpage with no special redirect
    } else {
        include('listabbrposts.php');  //a list of abbreviated posts for browsing
    }
} else {
    include('entry.php');  // a page with a single article
}
```

For a working example, you can check out my page where I use this technique: http://www.artfuladvection.com  click on a topic or tag from the left to see the redirect.

Comment: I'll just say using the longer approach will cause frustration and require edits in multiple files moving forward. You're better off using one of the preset permalink templates if you're new to wordpress.